# susy - no such file to load

Tags: css, sass

When I do require "susy" in my compass/sass config.rb file, I get "no such file to load -- susy".  I know I only have one instance of Ruby gems.  The documentation says that this error tells me I have more than one instance.  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Do you have a `Gemfile` in your project?

Comment: Do you have Susy installed?